# untracked files due failed pulled request

Tags: git

My colleague committed a bunch of stuff to git and I committed my changes.

The changes do not overlap, so there should be no need to merge.

I called 'git pull' but half way through I got an error message about long filenames.

I fixed the git settings and then called 'pull' again, but now git tells me that:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
> by merge:

Looking through the list of files those are the same files that my colleague added just earlier.

So it seems my project is kinda in no-mans land, git pulled some of the files but because of the filename length error it lost track of what's mine and what's not.

Any way to fix this without clean / fetch / reset?

**PS1:** I guess I can locally delete the files my colleague added and they will get pulled again, but just wondering if there's a smarter way

**PS2:** not sure if it helps but 'git status' gives me this messages:

> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 21
> different commits each, respectively.   (use "git pull" to merge the
> remote branch into yours)

Comment: Do you work on same branch? (you should not)

Comment: Yes, we both work on master. I know it's not best practice but our work is nearly 100% segregated.

Comment: You should work on own branches and merge to master. Otherwise you will always get `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have N and M different commits each, respectively`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are changes in your local branch that are not in the remote branch and vice versa. You must pull the remote branch before pushing your commits. If you're POSITIVE that your files do not overlap. Just stash your untracked files using

```
git stash -u
```

then do your pull as you would normally do.

Subsequently, you can start pushing the files again.

Answer (score 0):

### Configure `pull.rebase` and `rebase.autoStash`

Try using settings to autoStash your current changes and rebase on pull.

```bash
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

You can omit the `--global` if you want to test this only on the current repository.

If you must collaborate on the same branch these settings will

- Automatically stash changes before pulling and apply them again after pulling
- Automatically use the rebase strategy when pulling. Remote changes to the branch are applied *first* so you can continue editing your changes on top

Tutorials for further reading:

- [Leo Siddle - Git config: pull.rebase and rebase.autoStash](https://leosiddle.com/posts/2020/07/git-config-pull-rebase-autostash/)
- [Atlassian - Git Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash)
- [Atlassian - Git Rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)